# Probabilities and infinite sets

Tags: probability, infinity

First off, when searching for this question I didn't find anything exactly like what I'm asking, but if someone finds a duplicate post please let me know.

Here is my question:

Say that you have an infinite amount of sets, each containing one blue object and ten green objects, totaling 11 objects in each set.

Then say we have an infinite set P as the set containing all these little sets.

What are the probabilities that, reaching into set P, you'd pick out a blue or green object? Are they still 1/11 and 10/11, respectively?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's call $S_i$ each small set, with $i=1, 2, \ldots, +\infty$. Which is the probability to pick $S_i$?

Comment: @the_candyman Shouldnt the answer be independent of the probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You are right. It does not matter. I improved my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $S_i$ each small set, with $i=1, 2, \ldots, +\infty$. Suppose that $p_i$ is the probability to pick the set $S_i$. Then, you know that:

$$P(\text{blue} | S_i ~\text{has been picked}) = \frac{1}{11},$$
$$P(\text{green} | S_i ~\text{has been picked}) = \frac{10}{11}.$$

Moreover:

$$P(\text{blue}) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}P(\text{blue} | S_i ~\text{has been picked})p_i = \frac{1}{11}\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i,$$
$$P(\text{green}) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}P(\text{green} | S_i ~\text{has been picked})p_i = \frac{10}{11}\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i.$$

By definition,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i = 1,$$

then

$$P(\text{blue}) = \frac{1}{11},$$
$$P(\text{green}) = \frac{10}{11}.$$

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have an additional question if you can answer it: Say you thought of the blue and green objects in terms of belonging in their own respective, infinite sets... would they not be both technically the "same size" considering they're both infinite and thus would have an equal probability of having one of their members picked?

Comment: @progatician I don't understand your question... do you mean that you want to do the union of all the "green" and the union of all the "blue", and then work on these two sets?

Comment: Yeah, by grouping them differently does the probability result change?

Comment: @progatician in this case you need to denote with a sequence the elements of the new set. Let $a_j$ be the $j$-th elements. Then: $$a_j = \begin{cases}
\text{blue} & \text{if}~ j \equiv 0 (\text{mod} ~11) \\
\text{green} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$ Can you continue from this point?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @progatician you are welcome!